# Online Saltstack Minions on Azure losses connection with Master on DigitalOcean

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I have a salt 2016.11.3 (Carbon) playground with a master in DigitalOcean and 4 minions in Azure (three ubuntu and 1 windows).

After a while ubuntu minions are not responding to `salt -t 30 '*' test.ping` but they are online ( I can ssh into them )

Restarting the master `systemctl restart salt-master` or minions `systemctl restart salt-minion` seems to bring minions back for a while.

Things checked:

- <strike>Azure machines are put to sleep and only woken up on external events</strike> ✗
- <strike>The network between the two clouds is very slow</strike> ✗
- <strike>salt master machine is too small</strike> ✗
- <strike>salt minions do not ask master for "work"</strike> ✗
- <strike>salt-master hangs for some reason</strike>
- salt-minion communication error ✔

Also after restart I get a double response from re-added nodes but I think this is a cache problem because it disappears after some time (cache invalidation).

Comment: no, machines are not put to sleep. `The network between the two clouds is very slow` - too vague

Comment: `salt -t 30` means wait 30 seconds for an answer from minions. If the response is not arriving in 30 seconds something is very slow.

Comment: Not sure where your guesses came from, as Azure VMs don't magically go to sleep. If you started them, they're running. Which you've already proven because you were able to `ssh` into them. Same with network speed - I can't imagine that would ever be your issue, esp. for a connectivity test. Have you looked at how the minions listen for traffic, and how they deal with ports that eventually close due to timeout, and then retry?

Comment: Strikethrough my wrong guesses ( or else all azure people on stackoverflow will downvote my question :D ). Looking at saltstack minions now.

Comment: first, check both salt-master and minion running the same version.

Comment: Same version. I created identical servers.

Comment: Have you read the logs? Usually, when a minion is not controllable anymore there is somethings written in the corresponding logfile - either the master or the minion encouter an error. On your (ubuntu) minions check `/var/log/salt/minion` and on your master `/var/log/salt/master`. Please add error output that seems to be related to your answer.

Comment: it seems like is a tonado ioloop error on all three ubuntu minions. `2017-04-12 19:46:25,193 [tornado.application][ERROR   ][7093] Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x7f626e7a2158>` but the ping response is as non-deterministic as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like is a communication error. There is an older 2013 [bug report](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6231) on saltstack [github repo](https://github.com/saltstack/salt) and [someone states in comments that AWS and Azure load balancers don't respect TCP keepalives](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6231#issuecomment-29879149).

Suggested solutions:

1. [add a cron to ping minions](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6231#issuecomment-35323395) each minute
2. [change some keepalive settings](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6231#issuecomment-200562537) in Azure minions config file

Until now solution #2 works for me.

```
tcp_keepalive: True
tcp_keepalive_idle: 60
```